# "Request method 'POST' not supported" when I try to save Person due to <form method="POST">

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

Controller methods where can be mistaken:

Here I go to URL "/create" with <form method="POST>

```
@GetMapping("/create")
    public ModelAndView create() {

        ModelAndView modelAndView = new ModelAndView();
        modelAndView.setViewName("/create.jsp");
        return modelAndView;
    }
```

This is create.jsp

```
<%@ page isELIgnored="false"%>
<%@ page contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8" %>

<html>
<head>
    <title>Create</title>
</head>
    <body>
        <h1>Create author</h1>
        <form method="POST" action="">
            Id <input name="userId"> <br>
            Last name: <input name="lastName"> <br>
            First name: <input name="firstName"> <br>
            Second name: <input name="secondName"> <br>
            Phone: <input name="phone"> <br>
            Hobby: <input name="hobby"> <br>
            BitBucketUrl: <input name="bitBucketUrl"> <br>
            <input type="submit" value="Create">
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

And finally @Postmapping method

```
    @PostMapping
    public ModelAndView createPerson(
    @RequestParam("id") String id,
    @RequestParam("lastName") String lastName, 
    @RequestParam("firstName") String firstName, 
    @RequestParam("secondName") String secondName, 
    @RequestParam("phone") String phone, 
    @RequestParam("hobby") String hobby, 
    @RequestParam("bitBucketUrl") String bitBucketUrl) {
    
            personCache.create(Person.builder()
                    .setId(id)
                    .setFirstName(firstName)
                    .setLastName(lastName)
                    .setSecondName(secondName)
                    .setPhone(phone)
                    .setHobby(hobby)
                    .setBitBucketUrl(bitBucketUrl)
                    .build());
    
            ModelAndView modelAndView = new ModelAndView();
            modelAndView.addObject("id", id);
            modelAndView.addObject("lastName", lastName);
            modelAndView.addObject("firstName", firstName);
            modelAndView.addObject("secondName", secondName);
            modelAndView.addObject("phone", phone);
            modelAndView.addObject("hobby", hobby);
            modelAndView.addObject("bitBucketUrl", bitBucketUrl);
            modelAndView.setViewName("/all.jsp");
            return modelAndView;
        }
```

Page all.jsp is working (realized in method @GetMapping("/all")).

I want, when the button "create" is pushed, go to page "/all", where I can see a new Person. But I take an error "Request method 'POST' not supported" in the terminal, and error "type=Method Not Allowed, status=405" in the browser.

Also I create default page index.jsp, and try modelAndView.setViewName("/index.jsp") in @PostMapping method, but unfortunately, even in this case, when I push "create" browser don't go to index.jsp

Comment: Your browser does get calls, not posts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In create.jsp I was written:

```
Id <input name="userId"> <br>
```

And in @PostMapping

```
ModelAndView modelAndView = new ModelAndView();
            modelAndView.addObject("id", id)
```

Banal inattention

Answer (score 3):

By default browser does get-requests only, so create another controller method with get-mapping and add person object to the model so that you can set values in the view page and when you press submit give post-mapping so that you can assign values that are entered in view page to the person object.

Comment: Thanks, half of the problem was solved. I create a controller method with get-mapping that shows "create.jsp". Then, I create a controller method with post-mapping, where a Person is created. When I push the "create" button, I catch an error in the terminal: Request method 'POST' not supported.
Can we go to private chat where I can send you my code?

Comment: Just post that error in the answer section or edit your question.

Answer (score 1):

Browser address bar sends GET requests.
You can use smth like Postman to send requests which you need.

Comment: Yes, postman can send a post request. I had thought that browser can send post request... lol
So, I can send post request from jsp wtih "<form method="POST" action="">"  ?

Answer (score 1):

Try giving form tag any other action other than root and also give that post-mapping the same action.

Comment: I tried for example action="all" or action="/all", @PostMapping("/all") or @PostMapping("all").
It doesn't solve a problem.